# Is it safe to clear the routing table with route -f?

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing

Im really green when it comes to networking.  I was playing around with a persistent route I had added, and came across another topic that covered how to remove persistent routes.

one said route delete  which worked.

the other said route -f would remove all persistent addresses.

well upon testing the latter, it purged ALL routes.  I had no connectivity until i restarted.  A route print is showing entries now and connectivity is working - but im concerned with what this may have affected (if anything) as the table is substantially shorter than it was prior.  (discounting the single persistent route I had added)

I would rather roll back a system image (assuming these are stored locally) than deal with ramifications such as virtual adapters no longer working or something else ive yet to discover.

Is this just a cache that will repopulate itself as items are used, or are routes added upon install of various softwares/features and i just did a really bad thing?

Comment: Usually, all routes are non-persistent routes. So I don’t think you’ll have any problems.

Comment: yes, to be clear only 1 route was listed as "persistent" which was the one I added.  Just want to be certain for obvious reasons.